# Delayed listing of updated document (Google Drive SDK)

Tags: google-drive-api

If I update a document in Google Docs and then do a list of files through the Google Drive SDK, there is a delay of around 1 minute till I see the updated version. Often it works directly the first time a do a listing (if I haven't done any in a while), but then if I update the document again in Google Docs, I almost always have to wait a minimum of 1 minute for the updated document to show up in the listings. (I look at the etag to see if has been updated).

I use the SDK for Objective C and iPhone.

I also tried to use the q variable to make the listing only fetch this single document, but it didn't make any difference. I've also tried using the "Changes: list" request but the same delay is present there.